# Execute Javascript Command in Selenium to get data from a webpage

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

```
    <h4>Lotus</h4>
```

What i want is to grab the **Lotus** Value from the **h4** tag , in another post I got the answer using a javascript command as follow:

```
document.getElementById('17285').getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].innerHTML;
```

and it worked fine.

What i want to do now is to use this javascript in Selenium.

I tried the following Code :

```
MsgBox driver.executeScript("javascript:document.getElementById('17285').getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].innerHTML;")
```

but I get an empty messagebox, does anybody know why.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: **here is a part of the HTML Page** 

    <div style="background-image:url(/vp4/_sales/LOTUS15//Visual_fr.jpg)" id="17171" data-opcode="LOTUS15" data-opcategory="EventDrivenSale" data-opopenday="6">
        
        <a id="linkSale" class="linkAccess" title="" href="/vp4/Home/Handlers/OperationAccess.ashx?operationid=17171" onclick="javascript:PrepareEventOnLinksAnchor(17171);">
        
        <h4>Lotus</h4>

Comment: Are you sure that you are using SeleniumIDE?

Comment: Noting that the ID's aren't matching, are those dynamic?  It's possible that the ID changes each time, you might want to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Your id in HTML(17171) dosen't match with id in code(17285). Try this:

```
MsgBox driver.executeScript("javascript:document.getElementById('17171').getElementsByTagName('h4')[0].innerHTML;")
```

Comment: True but still nothing in the messagebox